# Is using the stale method on collections possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to use `stale?` with a collection? For example, I'm developing a REST api that will allow the client to occasionally query the server to ask for the most up-to-date list of items. It would be nice if `stale?` could check a collection against my If-Modified.. header and send a 304 if nothing has changed.

Quick example:

```
def index
  @items = Item.all
  if stale?(@items)
    render json: @items
  end
end

def show
  if stale?(@item)
    render json: @item
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

For Rails < 5:

```
stale?(last_modified: @items.maximum(:updated_at))
```

For Rails >= 5 just:

```
stale?(@items)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like that

```
stale?(@items, last_modified: @items.order('updated_at ASC').last)
```

Second parameter, a hash called `additional_options` internally, is passed to [`fresh_when`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b40bd16b7b0810b9d5621339f243c4a9569ceb96/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/conditional_get.rb#L75) method which then does

```
{ etag: record, last_modified: record.try(:updated_at) }.merge!(additional_options)
```

where record is first arg, `@items` in your case, so by passing `last_modified` value you can overwrite it. I am not sure what about `etag` header itself, but this is worth a try anyway.

EDIT:

So I checked it and Rails considers response fresh/not stale if either Etag is different or last modified is greater than requested.

Comment: `@items.last.updated_at` might be a problem if you change i.e the first item. Better to go for something like `@items.order(:updated_at).last`